How to break in an engine after rebuilding at home?
I have a GM engine ( engine code A14XER) which suffered hydrolock damages and the cylinder block end needed complete rebuild as there was a hole in the oil sump due to piston snapping.
So I bought a new cylinder block, one new piston to replace the damaged one and new piston rings, new rod/main bearings and installed them.
I have now completed the assembly and am going to start if for the first time after the rebuild so what is the process for breaking in the rebuild engine. This engine's recommended oil by the manufacturer is fully synthetic 5w30 and its summer over here so temperature varies between 12 to 25 degrees Celsius
Ive read at places that I need to add mineral oil/racing oil for break in for first 100/200 miles and also read conflicting materials saying that its just a myth to use mineral oil and should be fine to use the manufacturer recommended oil from the start.
So what would the ideal suggestion be as this engine is not a performance engine and is from a simple family hatchback car.

Did you replace bearings and rings? If so, did you use OEM replacement parts? What was the method of reassembly?

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, Yes I did replace the bearing and rings. They were not OEM , they were good quality aftermarket ones with the correct sizes. Not sure what you meant by re assembly. I assembled it by hand by following repair manual and torquing up correctly and in correct sequence.

Did you break the glaze on the cylinders? With new rings, you need to ensure you seat the rings correctly. If you haven't assembled it correctly (to include breaking the glaze and getting the crosshatch right in the cylinders),  you won't get it broke in correclty.

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2. Thank  you for your response. Yup I had the machine shop hone the cylinders on it for me. Now im looking to start for the first time , ive already put plenty of assembly lube on contact points and bearing points, but not sure which oil to use for the first time after rebuild and how long to run it for etc

Do not use synthetic oil to break it in. Synthetic oil works too well and sometimes won't allow the rings to seat. If they don't seat properly, you won't get oil control from the bottom rings or all of the compression from the top. If your engine calls for 5w-30 oil, use a conventional oil of that weight. Run it for about at least 500 miles, but can be ran up to 1000 miles before your first oil change. At the first oil change, run your synthetic of choice at the given weight and you should be golden.

Thank you for your responses.
